# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE for specific index, or combined indices

Tags: mysql, on-duplicate-key

I have a table on which we've, up until this point, used an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query to populate and update, with a foreign key(`booking_id`) from the initial insert being the duplicate index for update cases.

```
        INSERT INTO ship_docs (booking_id, boarding_date, shipping_date, special_number)

        VALUES (bookingId, boardingDate, shippingDate, specialNumber)

        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        boarding_date = boardingDate, shipping_date = shippingDate, special_number = specialNumber;
```

We now need to introduce a `UNIQUE` constraint to prevent duplicates of `special_number`. This query will no longer function as intended, as although on first `INSERT` the `booking_id` as an `FK` will be unique to it's respective table, `special_number` still has it's potential for collision. Because they are inserted at the same time, the query now updates on the (if it exists) `special_number`. Is there any reason to pursue hanging onto this method?

I've already split the query into they're individual branches, but is it still possible to get the job done with only one? I understand the non-existence of `WHERE` clauses in this scenario, and I haven't been able to rationalize an `IF` statement as a solution as I wouldn't like the query to `UPDATE` with either incorrect or repeated values, as I am trying to prevent updates on the wrong row, and return information of the rejection, while still being able to edit or update `special_number`.

Is this attempt to keep this method not worth the benefits, or supposed time saved? Or is there a way to either specify the *only* `DUPLICATE KEY` to be used? Or a way to introduce a 'unique pair' index for the conjunction of the `booking_id FK` and the `special_number UNIQUE` indices?

Or should I just being doing separate queries.

Comment: ODKU processes ANY unique violation. If you must have different reactions on different possible violations (this cannot be processed using ODKU) you may use stored procedure and use complex checking logic in it.

Comment: There are four possible situations for the unique keys on the table: 1) unique index only on the *booking_id* column, 2) unique index only on the *special_number* column, 3) unique index on the *booking_id* column with another index on the *special_number* column (two seprerate indexes), 4) a single unique index on both the *booking_id* and *special_number* columns. The last one *may* (or not) solve your situation. The problem may be that if you want to change either the *booking_id* column or the *special number* column without changing the other you will end up with a new row in the table.

Comment: With the update statement you have above will not update the other columns if they are different in the original row. Add VALUES() around any columns you want updated with the values in the INSERT value list. As is, the UPDATE part will leave the values unchanged since the values updated come from the duplicate row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going the route Akina suggested somewhat. Because the other suggestions wouldn't exactly solve what I was hoping to take care of, and the limitations of the ODKU, for now I've just split it into separate calls, and will most likely come back to in with a stored procedure if need be.